# Ler arquivo e salvar linhas

Tags: java, arquivo

Estou querendo ler um arquivo txt gravando cada linha do arquivo em variaveis do tipo String, (que uso para salvar uns dados, de um programa basico que estou fazendo)
pensei em algo mais ou menos assim

```
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\lucas\\Desktop\\teste.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
         String linha1 = br.readLine();// Uma da variaveis 
         // String linha2 = (?) // Como pego a segunda linha do txt e salvo aqui ?
         // String linha3 = (?) 
         while (linha != null){
             SetFirst(linha);// Funcao do objeto o qual estao os dados guardados
             linha=br.readLine();



         }
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
        br.close();
        fr.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: E qual a duvida quanto ao código?

Comment: Gostaria de saber como armazenar as demais linhas do arquivo texto em diferentes variaveis, se possivel.

Comment: `List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("meuarquivo.txt"));`

Comment: Eita, bem complexo, mas vlw

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 5):

Uma das maneiras possiveis é usando [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) e armazenando cada linha em um indice:

```
   try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\lucas\\Desktop\\teste.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
        ArrayList<String> linhas = new ArrayList<>();
        String linha = ""; 

         while ((linha=br.readLine()) != null){

             SetFirst(linha);// Funcao do objeto o qual estao os dados guardados
             linhas.add(linha);

         }
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
        br.close();
        fr.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso esteja utilizando **Java 8**:

```
List<String> linhas = new ArrayList<>();
String caminho = "C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/teste.txt";

try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(caminho))) {
  stream.forEach(linhas::add);
} catch (IOException e) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}

//linhas.forEach(System.out::println);
```